# Parsing XML and showing messagebox not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Store>
  <Product>
    <Product_id>1</Product_id>
    <Product_name>Product 1</Product_name>
    <Product_price>1000</Product_price>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product_id>2</Product_id>
    <Product_name>Product 2</Product_name>
    <Product_price>2000</Product_price>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product_id>3</Product_id>
    <Product_name>Product 3</Product_name>
    <Product_price>3000</Product_price>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Product_id>4</Product_id>
    <Product_name>Product 4</Product_name>
    <Product_price>4000</Product_price>
  </Product>
</Store>
```

And I have the following code below which shows a messagebox for every single product:

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("e:\\product.xml");
        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Store/Product");
        string product_id = "", product_name = "", product_price = "";
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {

            product_id = node.SelectSingleNode("Product_id").InnerText;
            product_name = node.SelectSingleNode("Product_name").InnerText;
            product_price = node.SelectSingleNode("Product_price").InnerText;
            MessageBox.Show(product_id + " " + product_name + " " + product_price);
        }
    }
```

But for some reason, the code gets up to `foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)` and then just stops. Without showing an error or anything. I have tried adjusting a few things but nothing is helping. I develop on .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: Your Code seems fine maybe you, maybe you misplaced the XML file

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Store/Product");
```

"Store" is not a node in your XML file, so it will skip right over the foreach statement.  Change "Store" to "Table", and you'll be in business.